# TSQL: Split one column into two based on value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm not quite sure what I need to be asking to solve this problem, ie. whether this is subquery, group by, union/join question, or something else entirely...

I have a student results table setup something like this:

```
student gender class result
------- ------ ----- ------
Bob     M      Math  A+
Mary    F      Math  A+
Peter   M      Math  A+
Jane    F      Math  B
```

What I want to do is to be able to see the results aggregated by class, but see the gender differences. Eg (based on the above example table):

```
males females class result
----- ------- ----- ------
2     1       Math  A+
0     1       Math  B
```

I hope my question makes sense and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason why you are denormalizing data?  This is usually not the best idea (hence, why this query would be extremely simple if you were looking for a normalized result set).

Comment: The aim of this query is to be able to compare genders based on results. Eg. Do girls achieve more A+s than boys in Math?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The query you need would look like this, using [SUM()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) aggregations, and a [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

```
SELECT SUM(CASE
              WHEN Gender = 'M' THEN 1
              ELSE 0
           END) AS Males
   , SUM(CASE
            WHEN Gender = 'F' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
         END) AS Females
   , class
   , result
FROM student
GROUP BY class, result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CLASS,
RESULT,
SUM(CASE WHEN GENDER ='M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) MALE ,
SUM(CASE WHEN GENDER ='F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FEMALE
FROM TABLE_1
GROUP BY CLASS,RESULT
```